# How to add person to contacts from a message (person auto linked w/ facebook)

Tags: contacts, facebook, sms

I got a message from someone not in my contacts. The number was automatically recognized as one of my Facebook friends. How do I add this person to my Google Contacts without copying down the number and adding them manually? There is no "Add Contact" button...

Answer (score 2):

Head over to Contacts -> Options Menu -> Display Options. Under choose contacts to display, expand facebook and put a checkbox against All Contacts. The contact will now be saved to your Google Contacts

Comment: No, it hasn't. Sure, it shows up with my other contacts, but it isn't saved to Google Contacts. By that I mean it doesn't show up when I go to contacts.google.com on my computer. I want to actually create a contact with that name/number.

Answer (score 0):

Often times, you can tap and hold the message from the person and a menu will pop up. From that menu, you can select from a number of options, including "Add 'name' to Contacts". Click that, enter a name and fill out whatever other fields you want, and you should be good to go.