# How do I add a phone number to contacts from the text message app?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, contacts, sms

I have a text message sent from a phone number that is not yet linked in any other method.

Is there a way to use this message's number to create a new contact or modify an existing one directly from the text messaging application?

If it is relevant, I use Gmail for my contacts and have imported from Facebook.

I have Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich).

**What I've tried**

[This question is vaguely similar](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10401/how-to-add-person-to-contacts-from-a-message-person-auto-linked-w-facebook), but not quite what I'm looking for.

I know I can copy/paste the number if I open the "modify recipients" dialog, click on the number, and click/hold to open the cut/copy/paste tool.  I can also simply write down the number on paper.  I'm looking for an alternative.

There are no menu options if I select the message at the top-level of the Text app.

The menu options while in the text message thread don't seem relevant:

- Insert smiley
- Delete
- Set priority
- Add subject
- Modify recipients

The menu options if I click and hold on an individual message don't seem relevant:

- Delete message
- Forward message
- Copy message text
- Protect message
- View message details
- Add to task

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On my Android 4.0.4 if I click on the picture of the contact, I get option to save it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To add a contact that you haven't called yet, you can open the "People" app, then click the icon with the + in the bottom middle.

If I recall correctly, Android 4.4 was kind enough to include this option from the phone dialing screen.

Reference: [Android Tapp - What’s New in Ice Cream Sandwich Android 4.0 » Android 4.0 People App (Contacts)](https://web.archive.org/web/20120427104348/http://www.androidtapp.com/whats-new-in-ice-cream-sandwich-android-4-0/android-4-0-people-app/)

Answer (score 0):

Go to your main text screen and in the list of people who have texted you, for example

```
James
Mama
Caroline
555-555-5555
```

(tap and hold this number)

On menu it says *Add to Contacts*